# Selecting certain rows in multiple columns as a filter Tableau Worksheet

Tags: filter, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I want to create a filter that will select certain rows but across multiple columns.

I have a table like this

| Student Name | Math Test Date | Science Test Date | English Test Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ted | 11/23 | 11/23 | Not Taking English |
| Mary | Not Taking Math | Not Taking Science | 11/23 |

I want to create a filter where I can click on something like "Math" and then show the students who will inevitably take a math test and exclude those that said "Not Taking Math". In the same filter box, I also want to see people taking Science by checking a box saying "Science". This isn't my actual use case. Open to rearranging/changing my table to make it easier to filter like what I was describing. Basically I just want to see which students are taking certain classes in a dashboard. Also open to creating a new table/worksheet so I can create this filter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new at this and there is probably an easier way, especially if you're comfortable with R,  but sticking to Tableau the following seems to work:
Using Tableau Prep,  import your file as many times as you have subjects.

For the first one, say,  rename to "math" and filter to just student and "math test date" fields.  For "math test date" clean to exclude the missing value.  Compute two new fields, one being "subject" which is simply "math", the other being "testdate" and set that to the math-test-date.    Hide all except student, subject, and testdate.

Do the same for the other subjects, then UNION them all together.
That gives you a data table you can filter by subject to see who has a test in that subject on what date.